# Trying to understand the passing of arguments in JavaScript using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I don't understand the following, and I would like some enlightenment:

In Iron-Router I did the following:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myCollection', this.params._id);
```

And then in my publications script:

```
Meteor.publish('myCollection', function(id) {
    return MyCollection.find({_id: id});
}
```

This did not work... but as I passed this from the subscribsion function:

```
{_id: this.params._id}
```

And in the publications:

```
  return MyCollection.find(id);
```

It works... what is the difference?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the misspelling `myCollcetion` in your publish function?

Comment: Aijj! No, I hand typed the question, and unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't have a syntax checker (yet) so I missed the typo. In the code however, I just swapped the two values and it worked... but, judging by the answer you gave, I assume normal behaviour should be that there is no difference...

Comment: Correct, I would expect that there is no difference. I don't see anything above that would explain why your first attempt fails. If anything, the inverse would be more likely—to pass an object to the server, you need to use `EJSON.stringify` on the client and `EJSON.parse` on the server for it to survive going over the wire. Sending a simple string should work fine. If you want to post more code of the version that fails, perhaps we can find the cause.